# How can I map a derived class having a collection of entities with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

How can I map `Dogs` and `Cats` to have a collection of `Toys` but not `Rats` because they're not pets?

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Animal {
    public virtual ICollection<Toy> Toys { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Animal {
    public virtual ICollection<Toy> Toys { get; set; }
}

public class Rat : Animal {

}

public class Toy {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Animal Owner { get; set; }

    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
}
```

I tried, with fluent mapping, doing:

```
public class CatEntityConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Cat> {
    public CatEntityConfiguration() {
        HasMany(c => c.Toys).WithRequired(t => t.Owner);
    }
}
```

But `Owner` has to be of type `Cat`, not `Animal`, but then of course, `Dog` wants `Owner` to be of type `Dog`, not `Animal` or `Cat`. I could make a `Dog` and a `Cat` property on `Toy`, but that seems like a hack, not a solution.

Comment: The answer will depend on how you plan to map the inheritance. Do you want to map the base class `Animal` too, or do you want to keep EF oblivious of it, so that each subtype will have its own independent mapping?

Comment: @GertArnold the base class and the derived classes are already mapped. I suppose I should have marked Animal as abstract. But yes, Animal is an entity EF is aware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with Entity Framework is that it want's a *very tight relationship* between entities, it really does. If you say '`Toy`: you're allowed to have any `Animal` as an owner, but only some `Animal` types will have you as a child' then Entity Framework reads that as 'I can't allow `Toy` to have a reference to `Animal` implicitly, because `Animal` doesn't know anything *about* `Toy`, and `Toy` is actually related to a `Cat` or a `Dog`.'

The easiest way to fix this is to make `Pet` a class with `Toys`, then make `Cat` and `Dog` inherit the `Pet` class, where `Rat` is still an `Animal`:

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Pet : Animal
{
    public virtual ICollection<Toy> Toys { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Pet
{
    public int CollarColor { get; set; }
}

public class Rat : Animal
{

}

public class Toy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Pet Owner { get; set; }
}
```

EF will then create a `Pets` table with a `Discriminator` column and the properties of *both* our objects (`Dog` and `Cat` are no longer the database entities):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pets] (
>     [Id]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
>     [Discriminator] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
>     [Name]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
>     [CollarColor]   INT            NULL,
>     CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Pets] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
> );
>
> CreateTable(
>     "dbo.Pets",
>     c => new
>         {
>             Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
>             Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
>             Name = c.String(),
>             CollarColor = c.Int(),
>         })
>     .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
> ```

And when we add a `Cat` named `Frank`, we get:

```
Id  Discriminator   Name    CollarColor
1   Cat             Frank   NULL
```

If you don't like this DB structure, the other option is to create a `PetAttributes` class, of which each `Pet` gets one, and then `Toys` is part of that class, each toy is owned by a `PetAttribute`, and then life goes on. The only problem is your navigation becomes `Cat.Attributes.Toys`, but you could build a `get`-only property to get around that.

To get rid of that `Discriminator` column, we could add:

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<Pet>();
```

Then this build a new, but still non-optimal DB structure:

> ```
> CreateTable(
>     "dbo.Toys",
>     c => new
>         {
>             Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
>             Cat_Id = c.Int(),
>             Dog_Id = c.Int(),
>         })
>     .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
>     .ForeignKey("dbo.Cats", t => t.Cat_Id)
>     .ForeignKey("dbo.Dogs", t => t.Dog_Id)
>     .Index(t => t.Cat_Id)
>     .Index(t => t.Dog_Id);
> ```

So, the last and final option, create a `PetAttributes` class with the `Toys`:

```
public abstract class Pet : Animal
{
    public PetAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class PetAttributes
{
    [Key]
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(OwnerId))]
    public Pet Owner { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Toy> Toys { get; set; }
}

public class Toy
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PetAttributes Owner { get; set; }
}
```

We override `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Ignore<Pet>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Pet>().HasRequired(p => p.Attributes).WithRequiredDependent(a => a.Owner);
}
```

And we get a new table structure:

> ```
> CreateTable(
>     "dbo.Cats",
>     c => new
>         {
>             Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
>             Name = c.String(),
>             Attributes_OwnerId = c.Int(),
>         })
>     .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
>     .ForeignKey("dbo.PetAttributes", t => t.Attributes_OwnerId)
>     .Index(t => t.Attributes_OwnerId);
>
> CreateTable(
>     "dbo.PetAttributes",
>     c => new
>         {
>             OwnerId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
>         })
>     .PrimaryKey(t => t.OwnerId);
>
> CreateTable(
>     "dbo.Toys",
>     c => new
>         {
>             Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
>             Owner_OwnerId = c.Int(),
>         })
>     .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
>     .ForeignKey("dbo.PetAttributes", t => t.Owner_OwnerId)
>     .Index(t => t.Owner_OwnerId);
> ```

Then, we can move more attributes into `Pet` or `PetAttributes`, and create `get`-only properties for them if they are in `PetAttributes`:

```
public abstract class Pet : Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public PetAttributes Attributes { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Toy> Toys => Attributes.Toys;
}
```

> ```
> CreateTable(
>     "dbo.Cats",
>     c => new
>         {
>             Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
>             Name = c.String(),
>             Attributes_OwnerId = c.Int(),
>         })
>     .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
>     .ForeignKey("dbo.PetAttributes", t => t.Attributes_OwnerId)
>     .Index(t => t.Attributes_OwnerId);
>
> CreateTable(
>     "dbo.Dogs",
>     c => new
>         {
>             Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
>             CollarColor = c.Int(nullable: false),
>             Name = c.String(),
>             Attributes_OwnerId = c.Int(),
>         })
>     .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
>     .ForeignKey("dbo.PetAttributes", t => t.Attributes_OwnerId)
>     .Index(t => t.Attributes_OwnerId);
> ```

As we can see, EF makes it *difficult but not impossible* to map one entity as the many part of *multiple* other entity relationships. This is largely due to the type constraints: EF *also* makes it hard to make a mistake in relationships from *type* errors.